# getting error like:- [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException] Too many arguments

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my UserCreateCommand.php file  when command:- php artisan user-create   username password    getting error  like:-  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]   Too many arguments.

```
class UserCreateCommand extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'user-create';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Create user with password imediately';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    //
    $username=$this->argument('username');
    $password=$this->argument('password');
    $user= new UserDemo();
    $user->username=$username;
    $user->password=Hash::make($password);
    $user->save();
    $this->info('user has been cretaed');
}
}
```

Comment: get error when command: php artisan user-create username password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function handle()
{
    //
    $username=$this->ask('username');
    $password=$this->secret('password');
    $user= new UserDemo();
    $user->username=$username;
    $user->password=Hash::make($password);
    $user->save();
    $this->info('user has been cretaed');


}
```

working fine when used command:- php artisan user-create